# color calibration

Tags: monitor, colors, monitor-calibration

I bought a Datacolor SpyderX because I need to color calibtrate my Laptops and according to the site it was supported. One computer is runnung Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and one 21.10. With one it is possible to prepare calibration but when it starts all I get is a mistake saying there was an error and it can't calibtrate. With the other one, color calibration in Ubuntu is greyed out and I can't do anything. I can't just do commant line calibration as some sugestions say and the best software I found (Displaycal) is not supported any more becaus it is dependent on Python2.
I am out of ideas and to be honest I am pissed about missing support altough it should run.
Best

Comment: Yes. Sorry. I dont have my computers near but one should be 20.04 LTS, the other 21.04.

Comment: Where did you read that Linux is supported? Because it looks like that hardware requires proprietary software to work and that they only make software for Mac and Windows.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/color-calibrationdevices.html.en and if you check the argyllcms site: https://www.argyllcms.com/doc/instruments.html it says SpyderX is supported. Also in the past I saw a lot of people working with it but since Displaycal is unavailable there is no option.

Comment: Hmmm... I'm not so sure. Reading through the details and installation instructions, it doesn't look like there have been any updates in over ten years. The installation instructions reference Ubuntu 10.04 which is well over a decade old. It also doesn't look like many features were actually supported. It's best to defer to the hardware manufacturer for questions about support and their website says that software is required and system requirements are only for Mac and Windows.

Comment: There is a package `argyll` in Ubuntu repositories though. Do you have this package installed? Even though this documentation is very outdated it's possible that the software is still maintained especially if this is the same software in repos

Comment: It seems to be maintained. I installed it via sudo, manually tried to update it, no way to get things running. They need to either remove the argyll link from ubuntu documentation or write their own list of suported instruments. Just linking to argyll (argylcms) for supported devices just to find out your chosen device doesn_t work is not an option.